What to add to batch file to disable device from waking PC during sleep?
I have a batch file on my Windows 11 PC that puts it to sleep. I have a hotkey on my keyboard that runs the program when I press it, putting my PC to sleep.
But recently I've run into issues where my PC will wake itself up incessantly, sometimes even seconds after I put it to sleep. I believe this to be an issue related to my ethernet controller (Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (2) I225-V). I have WoL disabled everywhere, but when I run powercfg devicequery wake_armed in the command line, it still shows up. That is, until I found that I can also disable it in the command line using powercfg -devicedisablewake "Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (2) I225-V".
So this is great! Seems like the issue was solved. But I recently found out that this setting resets each time you reboot your machine. So my question is this:
Can I add a line to my batch file that puts my machine to sleep that would also disable the controller's ability to wake my PC? If this is possible, it would solve ALL of my problems that I've been troubleshooting for like a month. Greatly appreciate the help! For reference, the line of code in the batch file that puts my machine to sleep is below:
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

Have you tried putting the powercfg -devicedisablewake "Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (2) I225-V" in the batch file before the rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 command?

I did but it's possible I did it incorrectly. It just didn't put my PC to sleep when I tried to run it. I'm not super familiar with how batch files work when running multiple processes but I tried separating the 2 commands with a ;. Is that correct?

; is not correct. Try commandA && commandB  - Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB. See Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com

That didn't seem to work. But it may have worked by simply putting each command on a different line? Does that make sense?
EDIT: Putting each command on a different line did not work, while it did end up putting my machine to sleep, it did not remove the Ethernet Controller from the wake devices.

Had a thought, could it be failing when I use && because the first command (being the removal of the controller from the wake devices) can only be run by an admin? And running the batch file doesn't run as an admin?

That would explain it.

So is there a way to make the script run as admin? See I'm binding this program to a key on my keyboard, so I can put my PC to sleep quickly and easily. It'd be ideal to not have to right click, run as admin every time

Yes, to run the script as admin .. in Task Scheduler create a Task, name the task with no spaces and only letters, e.g. GoToSleep .... tick the Run with highest privileges in the first tab. Don't set any Triggers. In the Actions tab, Start a program, and reference your script.
To run the task on a command line or in a script , the syntax is schtasks /run /tn "GoToSleep". When that works, put that schtasks  line in a separate new script and run that from your bound keystroke.
